# Mobile Browser Emulator for Apple and Google devices

Tags: javascript, angular, responsive-design, mobile-safari, emulation

We have recently released our mobile friendly version of our #Angular (javascript) app. We used google chrome dev-tools to develop and test our UI, we also used different devices to end-to-end test. We had some difficulty to reproduce some of the device specific issues in Chrome dev-tools.

So, now we are looking for a mobile browser Emulator, any recommendation of any product out there that could helps us? If we can debug in the emulator that would be awesome.

The devices that we are supporting is Apple and Google devices (mobile and tablets). Our developers are using Windows for development.

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine refereed me to use [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com)

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion, for android emulator https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/